# Unit issues in Mathematica 9

Tags: units

I posted the following on the Google+ group `comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica` and had no luck with responses. I've done a Google search and, to the best of my ability, used the documentation center.

The post I made was as follows:

> I continue to receive "Unable to interpret unit specification m/s" (for example, but almost anything I attempt returns this message) with input: 
>   UnitConvert[55 mi/h,"m/s"] or UnitConvert[55 mi/h,m/s] or any other combination of quotes, omitted quotes, etc. Even the prediction/suggestion box, when I execute Quantity[55,"mi/hour"}, after it returns 55 mi/h, if I type in any combination of m/s, "m"/"s", "m/s", etc. into the box that opens when I select "Convert" in the prediction box yields the same "unable to interpret unit specification.

What am I missing? (As you may gather, I'm a *Mathematica* novice.)

Comment: Try `UnitConvert[Quantity[55 , "Miles"/"Hours"], "Meters"/"Seconds"]`.

Comment: That's the sam as the answer I posted to MathGroup this morning. (Which raises a protocol/meta-question: should folks be posting the same question to both MathGroup and here?)

Comment: @murray ask it on [meta.mathematica.se]. I believe it was discussed, but I cannot remember where.

Comment: @murray http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/367/16

Answer (score 7):

It seems, if you are not going to use the "proper long name", you need to use `Quantity`
Try

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[55, "mi/hour"], Quantity["m/s"]]
```

Comment: +1, exactly. You must use `Quantity`, otherwise it may not recognize what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks.Those work but the UnitConvert page in the Documentation Center and the sure doesn't make it seem like all that is necessary. For example: UnitConvert[Quantity[8.2,"Miles"],"Pounds"]].

Comment: @user5091, There's a "full" name for each unit, and then there are ways that you can type it that get properly recognized because WolframAlpha understands what you mean. If you do `InputForm[Quantity["m"]]` you'll see what I mean. That translantion only seems to be done inside `Quantity`. If you use the "full" name, you don't need the `Quantity` in `UnitConvert`

Comment: I agree however that it shouldn't be necessary to type `Quantity`. Perhaps it will be changed in the next upgrade.